# How to overwrite tags with useStyles() in React with MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to overwrite the Link tag of React-Router with makeStyles() to remove the link decoration. Am I using makeStyles incorrectly? The default text underline is still showing.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
  },
  Link: {
    textDecoration: "none",
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `makeStyles` function will not override any Mui-related style definitions. The usage of the makeStyles is to give you an easy way to create new classes and then use them.

For example:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    myLayout: {
        width: "auto",
        background: "red"
    }
}));
const classes = useStyles();
...
<div className={classes.myLayout}>
```

If you want to override entire definition of Mui component, you will need to know which component it is, what it's internal Mui name, and then you can use the `createMuiTheme` for that:

```
const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiLink: {
            root: {
                textDecoration: "none"
            }
        },
    }
});
...
<MuiThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
    <Link />
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

If you want to change only one specific link (and not to override the style definitions of all the links in your website) you can use the `makeStyles` and then use the specific class in the `<Link />` component:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    noDecoration: {
        textDecoration: "none"
   }
}));
const classes = useStyles();
...
<Link className={classes.noDecoration}>
```

> Note - if you are using the `<Link />` component from react-router-dom - this is not a MUI component, so it will not have any MUI related classnames. You can [check the example here](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#link) on how to design the router's link based on the MUI components.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to pass the muiTheme I created to the entire component, instead of including it as a tag?